# magento 2 how to get cms blocks toOptionArray

Tags: collection, cms-block, array

```
<?php
 namespace [Vendor\Module]\Model\System\Config;
 use Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\CollectionFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

 class CmsBlocks implements OptionSourceInterface
 {
   /**
    * @var array
    */
    private $options;

   /**
    * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\CollectionFactory
    */
    private $collectionFactory;

  /**
   * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\CollectionFactory    $collectionFactory
  */
   public function __construct(
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
   ) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
   }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
   public function toOptionArray()
   {
      if (!$this->options) {
         $this->options =       $this->collectionFactory->create()->toOptionIdArray();
      }

      return $this->options;
   }
 }
```

it complains Array to string conversion
Can anyone guide why i am getting this

I am trying to call this in admin grid

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'cms_block',
        'select',
        [
            'name'      => 'cms_block',
            'label'     => __('CMS Block'),
            'title' => __('CMS Block'),
            'options'   => $this->_cmsBlock->toOptionArray(),
        ]
    );
```

Admin grid

```
<?php
```

namespace [Vendor\Module]\Model\Block\Adminhtml\TestModule\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
use [Vendor\Module]\Model\Model\System\Config\CmsBlocks;

class Adverts extends Generic implements TabInterface
{

```
/**
 * @var \[Vendor\Module]\Model\\Model\System\Config\Store
 */
protected $_cmsBlock;


public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Registry $registry,
    FormFactory $formFactory,
    CmsBlocks $cmsBlock,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_cmsBlock = $cmsBlock;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}

/**
 * Prepare form fields
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form
 */
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    /** @var $model \Magetop\Helloworld\Model\PostsFactory */
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('testmodule_testmodule');

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('post_');
    $form->setFieldNameSuffix('testmodule');
    // new filed

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'base_fieldset',
        ['legend' => __('Adverts')]
    );

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField(
            'entity_id',
            'hidden',
            ['name' => 'id']
        );
    }

    $fieldset->addField(
        'cms_block',
        'select',
        [
            'name'      => 'cms_block',
            'label'     => __('CMS Block'),
            'title' => __('CMS Block'),
            'options'   => $this->_cmsBlock->toOptionArray(),
        ]
    );


    $data = $model->getData();

    $form->setValues($data);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
/**
 * Prepare label for tab
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabLabel()
{
    return __('Posts Info');
}

/**
 * Prepare title for tab
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabTitle()
{
    return __('Posts Info');
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function canShowTab()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isHidden()
{
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: I have tried this way but not returning expected values
'$data = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        // $options = [];
        $options = $data->toOptionArray();

            foreach ($options as $block) {
                $options = ['label' => $block['label'],'value' => $block['value']];
            }
        

        return $options;'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
namespace [Vendor\Module]\Model\System\Config;
use Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class CmsBlocks implements ArrayInterface {

/**
    * @var array
    */
    private $options;

   /**
    * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\CollectionFactory
    */
    private $collectionFactory;

  /**
   * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\CollectionFactory    $collectionFactory
  */
   public function __construct(
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
   ) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
   }

public function toOptionArray(){

   $options = array();
   $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();

   foreach($collection as $block){
      $options[] = [
           'value' => $block->getData('identifier'),
           'label' => $block->getData('title')
      ];
   } 
   return $options;
}

}
```

And try change the addField like this:

```
          $fieldset->addField(
                'cms_block',
                'select',
                [
                    'name' => 'cms_block',
                    'label' => __('CMS Block'),
                    'title' => __('CMS Block'),
                    'options' => $this->_cmsBlock->toOptionArray()
                ]
            );
```

Comment: I did try this but i was getting following error Notice: Array to string conversion in vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Select.php on line 114

Comment: i've edited my answer check what implements the class now

Comment: I am still getting the same error  Array to string conversion

Comment: Seems like the issue is not here, can you show me the declaration inside the admin grid of the class? (Use, construct...) and try to remove the last comma: $this->_cmsBlock->toOptionArray(),

Comment: added to the question now

Comment: Still the same error occurs after removing the last comma after: toOptionArray(), ?

Comment: No same error again

Answer (score 1):

I think i have found the answer but not sure why this worked.

```
public function toOptionArray(){

    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $options = array();

    foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {

        $options[$key] = $value['title'];
    }

    return $options;
```

But now the value I selected won't save

Comment: it wont save because if that's a custom form you'll have to manually set it in the save action controller